# Phpstorm remove the bg from folders list

Tags: php, phpstorm

In open ssh session with vagrant im getting white bg on folders list and i dont find where to change this. its not in the console colors. someone know how to change this?

[image: phpstorm]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `tag name` from the background option.

The path would be like `File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts`.

Comment: can you be more specific please? i dont find this.